# JPA/Hibernate finds no mapped classes after deployment

Tags: java, eclipse, hibernate, jpa

### Short Version

I've got a Java-project which uses **JPA 2.0** with **Hibernate 4.3.4**. All is fine when I run it inside **Eclipse**. But when I let Eclipse export a runnable **JAR**, the trouble begins and the program crashes due to a seemingly missing persistence unit...

```
javax.persistence.PersistenceException: No Persistence provider for EntityManager named MyDBManager
at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:61)
```

... **or** seemingly unmapped classes...

```
3024 Thread-4| FATAL DbManager : DBManager could not load countries from database.
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: Country is not mapped [SELECT x FROM Country x]
at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1750)
at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1677)
at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1683)
at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.createQuery(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:331)
```

### Background

Depending on the kind of export (extracting vs. packaging vs. copying libraries), I run into different errors which resist solving. The furthest I get is with the last approach, which is also the one I have to choose for license reasons, so let's focus on that one.

In this case the exported JAR fails to look into its persistence.xml. I will specify that later but first some background information...

#### Folder Structure

- some_folder

  - myproject_lib
  - myproject.jar

    - root of my project's package structure
    - meta-inf

      - persistence.xml

#### File *persistence.xml*

```xml
<persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" version="2.0">
    <persistence-unit name="MyDBManager" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
        <!-- <exclude-unlisted-classes>false</exclude-unlisted-classes> -->
        <!-- <class>isi.eload.core.Country</class> -->
        <properties>
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
            <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect" />
            <!-- Do not define a connection here - this is done by the DbManager according to the command line arguments -->
            <property name="hibernate.id.new_generator_mappings" value="true" />
            <!-- <property name="hibernate.archive.autodetection" value="class, hbm" /> -->
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

I played around with the commented lines, once I felt that the xml is actually processed (see below) but that didn't help.

#### JPA/Hibernate JARs

Essentially the ones from the [4.3.4 Final Release](http://hibernate.org/orm/downloads/):

- antlr-2.7.7
- dom4j-1.6.1
- hibernate-commons-annotations-4.0.4.Final
- hibernate-core-4.3.4.Final
- hibernate-entitymanager-4.3.4.Final
- hibernate-jpa-2.1-api-1.0.0.Final
- jandex-1.1.0.Final
- javassist-3.18.1-GA
- jboss-logging-3.1.3.GA
- jboss-logging-annotations-1.2.0.Beta1
- jboss-transaction-api_1.2_spec-1.0.0.Final

.

### Failing with persistence.xml

#### Packaged meta-inf

As I hinted at before, the exported JAR fails to properly process the persistence.xml. When I execute it in the above folder structure, the following exception is thrown:

```
javax.persistence.PersistenceException: No Persistence provider for EntityManager named MyDBManager
at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:61)
```

This exception is usually thrown when the file was found but the persistence unit name given to `Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory` does not match any persistence unit declared in the files. But this is definitely not the case here!
I have no good idea, why this exception is thrown.

When I edit the JAR file (though I'm not sure that such tampering is not causing problems on its own) and empty or remove the persistence.xml, the error stays the same.

#### Another meta-inf

My first response was to copy a *meta-inf* folder next to the JAR:

- myproject_lib
- myproject.jar

  - ... unchanged ...
- meta-inf

  - persistence.xml

This seems to work, as an entity manager factory can now be created. But then no Entities are found and I think this is related to the fact that the *persistence.xml*, which is actually used, is not "on the same class path" as the JAR file.

Is there a link or an idea for how I can fix this? Preferably by forcing the JAR file to use the meta-inf folder which it contains itself.

Comment: META-INF needs to be upper case. I suspect that you are running on windows so if Java is attempting to access the filesystem META-INF/persistence.xml will be automatically translated to meta-inf/persistence.xml by the operating system. Once you package it up to a JAR it becomes case sensitive and stops working.

Comment: Wow! In knew it was going to be something trivial, but **that** is simply ridiculous! The hours I wasted...

Please make this an answer and I will accept, upvote and worship it on the shrine of RTFM. ;)

Comment: Did it work? If so I'll post it as an answer for cred ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`META-INF` needs to be in upper case. If Java is attempting to access the filesystem on Windows (or OS X in that regard) `META-INF/persistence.xml` will be automatically translated to `meta-inf/persistence.xml` by the operating system. Once you package it up to a JAR it becomes case sensitive and stops working.